# how do i find the positions of mulitple occurrences of a word in a list in python?

Tags: python

i am trying to get the positions of the word the user types in, but I can only find the position if the word only appears once in the sentence, how do I find the position if the inputted word appears multiple times in the sentence?

```
if varInput in varwords:
    print ("Found word")
    #prints total number of words
    print("The total number of words is: "  + str(len(varwords)))#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272358/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-times-a-word-occurs-in-a-sentence-python
    #finds out how many times the word occurs in the sentence
    wordOcc = (varwords.count(varInput))
    #if word occurence = 1 then print the position of the word
    if wordOcc ==1:
        pos = varwords.index(varInput)
        pos = pos+1
        print("the word "+varInput+" appears at position:")
        print(pos)

    else if wordOcc =>2:
        pos1 = varwords.index(varInput)
```

Comment: Have a look here: ["How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

The `.index` method will only return the first occurrence; it is not an iterator that yields different values.

However, there is a quite easy way to find all of the occurrences. You can run over the indexes of the words array, and add the ones where the item is the specified word:

```
indexes = [i for i in range(len(sentence)) if sentence[i] == word]
```

This will return all of the occurrences as a list, or an empty list (with `len(indexes)==0`) if the word does not happen to be found.