# How many times a different word appear in a string - python

Tags: python

For example I have `GolDeNSanDyWateRyBeaChSand` and I need to find how many times the word `sand` appears.

```
text = input()
text = text.lower()
count = 0

if "sand" in text:
    count += 1

print(count)
```

But the problem is that there is 2 `sand` in this string and when it found the first one it stops. Im a beginner in the programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272358/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-times-a-word-occurs-in-a-sentence

Comment: You can use the built-in functions (like text.count()) or two pointers approach (l - first symbol, r - last, move forward sliding window and check substring text[l:r+1] while r < len(text) )

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the str.count() method to count how many times a string appears in another string.

```
text = input()
text = text.lower()
count = text.count("sand")
```

Answer (score 0):

To find every occurrence of a string `pattern` inside another string `s`, even nested occurrences, do the following:

```py
s = "sandsandssands"  # your string here
pattern = "sands"     # your pattern here

pos = -1
end_of_string = False

while not end_of_string:
    pos = s.find(pattern, pos+1)
    print(pos)
    end_of_string = (pos == -1)
```

#### Output

```
0
4
9
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the solution offered by the OP.
The idea is to use `find` and move to towards the end of the string.
It is clear that `count` can be used here and the solution below is for educational purpose.

```
text = 'GolDeNSanDyWateRyBeaChSand'
word = 'sand'
ltext = text.lower()
offset = 0
counter = 0
while True:
    idx = ltext.find(word, offset)
    if idx == -1:
        break
    else:
        counter += 1
        offset = idx + len(word)
print(f'The word {word} was found {counter} times')
```

output

```
The word sand was found 2 times
```